# JDBC Access Update Query

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, ms-access-2007

I have an Update Query Problem with jdbc and Access. The database name is 'avi' and it has a table called 'part1' inside it.! [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qThR.png)

The code:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:avi");
Statement statement = con.createStatement( );
String queryTemp="UPDATE part1 SET level=5 where qid=1";
statement.executeQuery(queryTemp);
```

The table does have an entry with qid=1.
Here's the console error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in
 UPDATE statement.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3110)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:338)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:2
```

53)
        at Conn.updt(Conn.java:47)

Line 47 is statement.executeQuery(queryTemp);

Am I going wrong in the Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add square brackets to reserved words:

```
[level]
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-reserved-words-HP001032249.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Replace above statement

```
statement.executeUpdate(queryTemp);
```

with

```
statement.executeQuery(queryTemp);
```

"executeQuery()" is used for ddl statemets ,when "executeUpdate()" is used for dml statements like insert,update which is related to row operations!!!!!!!!